# Extend ansible role?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am writing my first ansible playbook and try to configure php 7 by using already existing roles. I found 2 roles that nearly suit my needs but both of them do not offer the flexibility I want for creating `php.ini` files.

1. https://github.com/itcraftsmanpl/ansible-role-php7

This role uses a task called `php-fpm.yml` to change lines in a already existing `php.ini` file using

```
- name: Ensure timezone is set in fpm php.ini
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
              regexp='date.timezone ='
              line='date.timezone = {{ php_timezone }}'
```

2. https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-php/

This role uses a template for generating the `php.ini` and inserts certain predefined variables to make it configurable.

```
date.timezone = {{ php_date_timezone }}
```

Question:

Is it possible to add a new configuration directive (let's say for setting `mysqli.max_persistent=XYZ`) without overwriting the files of the above mentioned roles? Or do I have to stick to those config options the roles provide?

How should I in general extend a already existing role without tampering the file base of the role?

My current playbook.yml is as simple as this:

```
- name: Install PHP 7
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  roles:
   - ansible-role-php7
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [include_role](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_role_module.html) in your implementation.

For example `/roles/myphp/tasks/main.yml`:

```
- include_role:
    name: ansible-role-php7

- lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini
    regexp: 'mysqli.max_persistent ='
    line: 'mysqli.max_persistent = {{ mysqli_max_persistent }}'
  notify: restart php7-fpm
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I also solved this by using `include_role` in my custom php role. The main php role is installed using `ansible-galaxy`, so my playbook structure looks like this:

```
roles/
  php/
    defaults/
      main.yml
    templates/
      xdebug_config.ini.j2
    tasks:
      main.yml
requirements.yml
site.yml
```

In the `requirements.yml` file I specify all galaxy roles to install:

```
- src: geerlingguy.php
```

I then install the required role by executing:

```
ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
```

In my `site.yml` I then use my own role which extends the `geerlingguy.php` role:

```
---
# Sample playbook

- name: "Development playbook"
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: php
      tags: php
```

In the `roles/php/tasks/main.yml` we then use `include_role` and setup our extended tasks for this role:

```
---
# Extends the geerlingguy.php role.

- name: Include base php role.
  include_role:
    name: geerlingguy.php

- name: Setup xdebug configuration.
  template:
    src: xdebug_config.ini.j2
    dest: /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/xdebug_config.ini
    mode: 0777
```

You can use a `ansible.cfg` file to make sure that ansible can find the roles installed using `ansible-galaxy`, for instance:

```
[defaults]
roles_path=/etc/ansible/roles
```